# Freezed - creating subclasses

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON data structure from an API, which has some fields in it.

I want to create a Freezed model that has a factory to create the correct subclass, depending on one of the fields' type.

Here is my code:

```
abstract class ItineraryData<T> implements _$ItineraryData<T> {
  const ItineraryData._();

  const factory ItineraryData({
    List<dynamic> summary,
    double totalPrice,
    double totalSeparatePay,
    double totalTax,
    List<String> covidAlerts,
  }) = _ItineraryData;

  const factory ItineraryData.flight({
    List<FlightSummary> summary,
    double totalPrice,
    double totalSeparatePay,
    double totalTax,
    List<String> covidAlerts,
  }) = _FlightItineraryData;

  const factory ItineraryData.hotel({
    List<HotelSummary> summary,
    double totalPrice,
    double totalSeparatePay,
    double totalTax,
  }) = _HotelItineraryData;

  const factory ItineraryData.car({
    List<CarSummary> summary,
    double totalPrice,
    double totalSeparatePay,
    double totalTax,
    List<String> covidAlerts,
  }) = _CarItineraryData;

  factory ItineraryData.fromJson(Map json) => _$ItineraryDataFromJson(json);
}
```

When it's this way, accessing a reference of `ItineraryData<A>` would never have a `summary` list field (which should always be there, but with different type).

Then I tried to change the unnamed constructor to use `<T>` in the List type:

```
const factory ItineraryData({
    List<T> summary,
    double totalPrice,
    double totalSeparatePay,
    double totalTax,
    List<String> covidAlerts,
}) = _ItineraryData;
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `summary` because of type `T` (type parameter).
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.
To support type paramaters (generic types) you can:
1) Use `JsonConverter`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonConverter-class.html
2) Use `JsonKey` fields `fromJson` and `toJson`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/fromJson.html
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/toJson.html
3) Set `JsonSerializable.genericArgumentFactories` to `true`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonSerializable/genericArgumentFactories.html
package:<???>/models/itinerary_data.freezed.dart:253:17
    ╷
253 │   final List<T> summary;
    │                 ^^^^^^^
    ╵
[INFO] Running build completed, took 221ms
```

I did try adding a converter, like so:

```
class ItineraryDataConverter
    implements JsonConverter<ItineraryData, Map<String, dynamic>> {
  const ItineraryDataConverter();

  @override
  ItineraryData fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null || !json.containsKey('data')) {
      return null;
    }

    json = json['data'];
    // type data was already set (e.g. because we serialized it ourselves)
    if (!json.keys
        .any((k) => ['cabin_class', 'hotel', 'car_type'].contains(k))) {
      return ItineraryData.fromJson(json);
    }
    // you need to find some condition to know which type it is. e.g. check the presence of some field in the json
    if (json.containsKey('cabin_class')) {
      return _FlightItineraryData.fromJson(json);
    } else if (json.containsKey('hotel')) {
      return _HotelItineraryData.fromJson(json);
    } else if (json.containsKey('car_type')) {
      return _CarItineraryData.fromJson(json);
    } else {
      throw Exception(
          'Could not determine the constructor for mapping from JSON');
    }
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(ItineraryData data) => data.toJson();
}
```

But I still get the same error.

How can I make sure `summary` is visible + strongly typed from subclasses?

Or what would a better approach to this be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try adding custom converter for type `T`?

```
const factory ItineraryData({
  @CustomConverter() List<T> summary,
  ...


...

class CustomConverter<T> implements JsonConverter<T, Object> {
  const CustomConverter();

  @override
  T fromJson(Object json) {
    // TODO: implement fromJson
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Object toJson(T object) {
    // TODO: implement toJson
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```